# Como criar e acessar uma variável global com PHP e codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Bom dia pessoal, estou com uma duvida estou usando o seguinte para gerar alertas de sucesso ou erros no meu sistema.

```
if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'> Cliente salvo com sucesso</div>";
    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', $msg);
    redirect('clientes');
} else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao inserir cliente</div>";
    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', $msg);
}
```

Vejam que eu possuo vários controllers e dentro desses controllers vários métodos se eu for colocar isso em cada método sera muito trabalhoso.

Gostaria de saber se tenho como criar a variável $msg de froma global para ser acessada por qualquer controller/método e onde eu crio ela.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, não se trata de criar outra *"variável global"*, e sim de uma função que leia a *SESSION*, que já é global. Sempre que vc precisar criar uma função (ou método) que deve ser acessado de forma *"global"*, use um *HELPER*, um *HOOK* ou uma biblioteca.

Minha sugestão: crie um *HELPER* que vai ler a *SESSION* `mensagem` e retornar um *alert* formatado de acordo com o comando do método.

Crie *applications/helpers/session_helper.php*:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if( ! function_exists('session_alert')){
    function session_alert(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['mensagem'])){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-'.$_SESSION['mensagem'][0].' alert-dismissible" role="alert">';
            echo '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"';
            echo 'aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>';
            echo '</button><strong>Aviso!</strong> '.$_SESSION['mensagem'][1];
            echo '</div>';
        }
        unset($_SESSION['mensagem']);
    }
}
```

Carregue o *HELPER* com [autoload](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html): `$autoload['helper'] = array('session_helper');`

Seu *controller* vai criar os avisos da mesma forma, só que passando um *array* com dados da mensagem para a `$_SESSION['mensagem']`:

```
if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', ['success','Cliente salvo com sucesso']);
    redirect('clientes');
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', ['danger','Erro ao inserir cliente']);
}
```

Como vc pode ver, a função `session_alert()` só vai mostrar o *alert* quando houver dados na `$_SESSION['mensagem']`. Assim, vc pode chamar essa função na  *VIEW* usando `<?= session_alert(); ?>` em qualquer *VIEW* do sistema.

Por exemplo, sua *VIEW* "clientes" pode ter algo assim:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <?= session_alert(); ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza o [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php) da seguinte forma:

```
$GLOBALS['msg'] = $msg;
```

E dentro de cada função tu pode chamar assim:

```
global $GLOBALS;
$msgGlobal = $GLOBALS['msg'];
```

Eu sugiro utilizar assim pois não sei o número nem de classes e funções que tu tem.